# What is the underlying transport protocol used by XmlHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am curious to know. Is it SOAP or plain HTTP or something else? I was checking XmlHttpRequest in wikipedia but there is no mention of it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It requests an XML Document over HTTP or HTTPS.

You can see all the details in the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest).

Answer (score 3):

As the name implies, it's HTTP: XML **Http** Request

Comment: You are exactly right. I missed that big time. :-) But you know what, XML is also there but XmlHttpRequest is not only for Xml.

Comment: You're right too :) But the transport protocol is still simple http/s

Answer (score 0):

Plain http(s), also, soap uses plain http(s) for the transfer in most cases, sometimes smtp.

It's in the name by the way, xml **http** request.